# wpf charting Why chart doesn't scroll ? Is it not possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, scroll

My charts have huge data and need it to scroll to view it properly. I tried adding scrollviewer to my userControl (that contains chart), to window, inside the chart but in no way I am able to scroll the chart. 
Am I trying something that's not possible or need another way out for the same. My UserControl xml :

```
<UserControl x:Class="WellBore.Graphs.BaseCaseSiReturnPlot"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1500">

<Grid>
    <DVC:Chart Name="siReturnChart" Title="Base Case Si Return" LegendTitle="Legend">
        <!-- Add Title on Y axis and X Axis -->
        <DVC:Chart.Axes>
            <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Chemical Concentration" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Location="Left" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Location="Bottom" Interval="100" />
            <DVC:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Title="Production time (days)" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Location="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DVC:Chart.Axes>

        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:LineSeries Name="layer1Chart" Title="Layer 1" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}"  />
            <DVC:LineSeries Name="layer2Chart" Title="Layer 2"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
            <DVC:LineSeries Name="layer3Chart" Title="Layer 3"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
            <DVC:LineSeries Name="layer4Chart" Title="Layer 4"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
            <DVC:LineSeries Name="layer5Chart" Title="Layer 5"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
            <DVC:LineSeries Name="wellChart" Title="Whole Well"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />                
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Window xml :

```
<Window x:Class="WellBore.Graphs.ViewGraphWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Graph Window" Height="680" Width="1300"   
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"Topmost="True" >
   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollB  Visibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True" Margin="0, -28, 0, 28" >
         <Grid Name="gridContent" Height="600" Background="DarkGray">
        </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

To add to the window grid :

```
private void AddChild(UserControl uc)
{
     gridContent.Children.Clear();
     gridContent.Children.Add(uc);
}
```

Any idea why the chart is not scrollable ? It just fits in the window size. Even maximize window doesn't make the chart data completely visible - dots are overlapped.

Scrolling such charts is very important for this chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `MinWidth` of the chart or maybe the `MaxWidth` of the `gridContent`?  Since no widths are set, the controls are defaulting to `Double.NaN` so they are sizing to however the control defines them to size.

Comment: I added MinWidth of chart to 800 & on making screen small I can scroll. But I want the chart to spread so can see the dots.

Comment: Added MinWidth, MinHeight, Height & Width to the chart. Removed Height from the Grid of the window. Finally vertical & horizontal scrolling got working.